# How can we resize a plot by a certain percentage

Tags: r

Is there a way to resize a plot by example 10% inside the device window?
I've tried the par function but I couldn't succeed it:

```
par(plt = c(10, 10, 10, 10)) 
plot(1:10)
```

Comment: I am not sure what attribute you want changed.

Comment: I want to make the plot seem smaller within the window

Comment: This link may be useful for you http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/index.htm

Comment: @user1945827: You are right. It is useful indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the margins

```
par(mar=c(6, 5, 5, 3))
```